# MS Access SQL - distinct records and count of related values

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate, distinct

I'm running into a problem with an aggregate query. I've got two tables, MainA and MainC. I want to select only unique values in MainA and then count the number of matches to those values from MainC. I don't care (for now) about values that show up in MainC that aren't in MainA. I've got a simple expression mostly working, which is here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TBMainA.Field1, Count(TBMainC.MCField1) AS CountOfMCField1
FROM TBMainA 
LEFT JOIN TBMainC ON TBMainA.Field1 = TBMainC.MCField1
GROUP BY TBMainA.Field1;
```

However, the problem is that if more than value shows up in MainA, the expression is double-counting the values in MainC (presumptively because there are two cases in MainA to count from). I suspect this has to do with where I'm starting the aggregation or how I'm grouping, but I've banged my head on this one for a bit and haven't produced a working solution yet. Here's some sample data along with the query output as it stands now (MAID and MCID are keys for each table):

MainA

| MAID | Field1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apples |
| 2 | oranges |
| 3 | grapefuit |
| 4 | peppers |
| 5 | kiwi fruit |
| 6 | tomatoes |
| 8 | avocado |
| 9 | bananas |
| 10 | apples |

MainC

| MCID | MCField1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bananas |
| 2 | peppers |
| 3 | peppers |
| 4 | tomatoes |
| 5 | apples |
| 6 | spinach |
| 7 | kale |
| 8 | apples |
| 9 | oranges |

Query output:

| Field1 | CountOfMCField1 |
| --- | --- |
| apples | 4 |
| avocado | 0 |
| bananas | 1 |
| grapefuit | 0 |
| kiwi fruit | 0 |
| oranges | 1 |
| peppers | 2 |
| tomatoes | 1 |

Suggestions welcomed, and thanks for your help...!

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68445621/query-for-access-table-results-with-no-duplicate-records-counted/68445732#68445732

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count distinct query MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720169/count-distinct-query-ms-access)

Answer (score 0):

For your particular query, then counting the unique values of `MCField1` would be:

```
SELECT Field1, COUNT(MCField1) AS CountOfMCField1
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TBMainA.Field1, TBMainC.MCField1
      FROM TBMainA LEFT JOIN
           TBMainC
           ON TBMainA.Field1 = TBMainC.MCField1
     ) as AC
GROUP BY Field1;
```

If you just want to count the number of occurrences, then:

```
SELECT TBMainA.Field1, COUNT(*)
FROM TBMainA LEFT JOIN
     TBMainC
     ON TBMainA.Field1 = TBMainC.MCField1
GROUP BY TBMainA.Field1;
```

Comment: Hi Gary - this looks good with one add -- since "apples" shows up twice in MainC, shouldn't the count for it = 2 for the one unique entry for it from MainA...?

Comment: Hi Gary - it looks like this one doubles up the counts as the first one did. I'm looking for something that will a) produce a unique list of values from MainA (so even though apples is listed twice, it will only show up once) and then provide a count from MainC (so if apples is listed twice in MainC, you'd see a count of 2). Right now it's returning a higher count since it looks like it's counting the total in MainC twice (once for each occurrence in MainA). I might actually split my queries up since I'm not actually sure it's possible to do what I'm hoping to do in one expression.

Comment: Gary - also, I just wanted to thank you for continuing to work on this - your efforts are really appreciated....!